# Are there any libraries/APIs that can take a large audio file and identify music in it?

Tags: audio-processing

I'm trying to process large video/audio files and extract timestamps and songs played during the video.

For example, processing a large Twitch stream VOD to find out that songs A, B and C were played at time stamps 1:00:23- 1:03:12, 1:34:23-1:38:43, and 2:21:56-2:24:45.

The ideal solution would be a library I could use to run this locally since I don't think any APIs would want to handle large audio files hours long.

I've looked at a few different libraries such as aubio and shazamcli already, but they don't seem to fit what I'm trying to do. I'm not too familiar with the audio processing space overall.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, or other off-site resources are off-topic. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: There is s relevant thread of software recommendations https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/free-music-recognition-api